# Meaning of Science Block (British English)

Tags: british-english

In the British radio comedy show, Cabin Pressure, the following exchange of dialogue occurs:

> Martin: Your doctor? What doctor do you know?
>
> Simon: Good old Doc Smiley, of course.
>
> Martin: What, Nathan Smiley from school?
>
> Simon: That’s right! Remember him, do you?
>
> Martin: Of course I remember him, he threw my briefcase on the science block - and he’s a podiatrist!
>
> Simon: And a bloody good one.

What does "science block" mean in this context? It seems to be some Britishicism, but I'm not entirely sure of the meaning.

Comment: Any chance it simply refers to a building that hosts the science department?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a British English speaker, I would use "science block" to mean "the science labs and classrooms in a secondary school" rather than a college or university (those I'd be more likely to call the "science department").

In this context it definitely refers to secondary school (that's ages 11 - 16).

Further, a "science block" has connotations of being in some way separated from the main school buildings (off to one side or a separate structure entirely) and I would picture a single storey building from that. Whilst it's not easy to throw a briefcase on top of a single storey building it's not impossible. And indeed, half the joke comes from the image - it takes a determined and/or a large and strong bully to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Here it means 'science wing' or the part where they study 'science' in a college or university.

A building or part of a complex used for a particular purpose. For example, a shower block

**More examples from Oxford Dictionaries:**

> - The completion of the *science block* is not the end of developments at the School.
> - But the school burned down and many classrooms and hostel *blocks* were    completely destroyed.
> - A women's centre and an urban prayer garden complete the Cathedral    *block*.

Comment: But how do you throw a briefcase onto a building?

Comment: @curiousdannii Yes it seems interesting! (May be he threw it from a floor of some other block).